# In case of heat transfer by conduction without any heat generation , will a material with higher diffusivity reach steady state faster?

Tags: thermodynamics

I couldn't really understand the physical meaning of thermal diffusivity.As far as I could imagine, a material with high diffusivity(High conductivity and low specific heat capacity) can reach steady state much faster than a material with lower thermal diffusivity.

Comment: Yes, it will be faster.

Comment: Please explain it.I  couldnt imagine it clearly.I have just got a rough idea about it.But most of my teachers explained it like "if diffusivity is high, heat can be transfered faster through the medium".(I am just an under grad student(i.e.) I have dealt only with  steady state heat transfer in 1 dimension)

Comment: Are you familiar with the transient heat conduction equation and are you familiar with dimensional analysis?

Comment: Yes .I just know what the equation is (I think you are mentioning the second order partial differential equation) i.e. we derive it and remove a lot of terms and use it.I am a bit familiar with dimensional analysis.

Comment: Well, if you apply dimensional analysis to your transient heat transfer equation, you find that the time scale for the heating is $L^2/\alpha$, where L is th length scale for the object and alpha is the thermal diffusivity.